# shopping cart rules is not working correctly for two different rules

Tags: magento-1.9, shopping-cart-price-rules

I have created two different shopping cart rules to apply discount when i check it on front-end it is showing incorrectly.it was applied both rule same time as there are different condition for both rules.

Here is how my rule condition look.
First rule to be applied on selected product only.

https://www.screencast.com/t/gNCBtJu6BgA

second rule to be applied on non selected product only

https://www.screencast.com/t/fgJ6h3cX

How its look on front-end
https://www.screencast.com/t/ib7B8jlV

it should only applied to selected product but it is applying both rule.

Can any please help me on this.

Comment: can you go to `Actions` and than select `Stop Further Rules Processing` to `yes`.... http://prntscr.com/g46a9w , also make sure you gave different `priority` for both......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to **Actions** and than select **Stop Further Rules Processing** to yes....  , also make sure you gave different **priority** for both......

[image]